# PLaying Default Video in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have parsed RSS feed http://www.teluguone.com/videosongs/videoSongsXml.php?cat_id=6.
And displayed songpics in Horizontal List view. As shown below
[image]

When I click on a particular song it was playing in the space above.
But,here I want to get default video along with Horizontal list view.And when I click on a particular video it should be played.
How to get the default video along with List view.

**XAML code:**

```
    <phone:PhoneApplicationPage
    x:Class="PhoneApp1.MainPage"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:phone="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
   xmlns:shell="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Shell;assembly=Microsoft.Phone"
   xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
   xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
   xmlns:delay="clr-namespace:Delay;assembly=PhonePerformance"
   mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignWidth="480" d:DesignHeight="768"
   FontFamily="{StaticResource PhoneFontFamilyNormal}"
   FontSize="{StaticResource PhoneFontSizeNormal}"
   Foreground="{StaticResource PhoneForegroundBrush}"
   SupportedOrientations="Portrait" Orientation="Portrait"
   shell:SystemTray.IsVisible="True" Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded">

<!--LayoutRoot is the root grid where all page content is placed-->
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

 <!--TitlePanel contains the name of the application and page title-->
    <StackPanel x:Name="TitlePanel" Grid.Row="0" Margin="12,17,0,28">
        <TextBlock x:Name="ApplicationTitle" Text="Teluguone" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="PageTitle" Text="Songs" Margin="9,-7,0,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextTitle1Style}"/>
    </StackPanel>

 <!--ContentPanel - place additional content here-->
    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">

        <MediaElement x:Name="player" AutoPlay="True" Margin="0,0,0,282"/>

        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" Height="Auto" Margin="-60,411,-93,10"  >
            <ListBox x:Name="videosongList" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"
         ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" Height="200" Width="1000" SelectionChanged="videosongList_SelectionChanged" >
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Margin="0,50,0,0"  Orientation="Horizontal">
                            <Image  x:Name="img1" Source="{Binding songpic}"  ></Image>

                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding songname}"  TextWrapping="NoWrap"  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"
                                       FontSize="20" />


                        </StackPanel>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <ListBox.ItemsPanel >
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"></StackPanel>

                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
            </ListBox>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

**Code for XAML.cs:**

```
namespace PhoneApp1
   {
        public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
       {
          public MainPage()
        {
             InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // is there network connection available
             if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No network connection available!");
                return;
            }
            // start loading XML-data
            WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri("http://www.teluguone.com/videosongs/videoSongsXml.php?cat_id=6", UriKind.Absolute);
            downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(VideosongsDownloaded);
            downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
          }

          void VideosongsDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
            if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
            }
            else
            {
                // Deserialize if download succeeds
                XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
                XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(videosongs));
                videosongs videosongs = (videosongs)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
                videosongList.ItemsSource = videosongs.Collection;
            }
        }

    private async void videosongList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Songsdetails song = (Songsdetails)videosongList.SelectedItem;


        var url = await YouTube.GetVideoUriAsync(song.songcode, YouTubeQuality.Quality480P);
        player.Source = url.Uri;
    }
}

}
```

Anybody please give me any suggestion of getting default video playing along with horizontal list view.
Many Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try playing `Youtube` videos using the `Youtube` class from `Codeplex`.

[Youtube Class](https://mytoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=YouTube&referringTitle=Documentation)

or else you could refer the sample from msdn:

[Youtube Video sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Youtube-Video-Sample-f2692dc9)

Comment: Thank you  sir.I am refering Youtube class